# Проектирование структуры сайта

Tags: проектирование

Здравствуйте! Я новичок, поэтому вопрос ниже заданный может показаться немного глупым, но прощу ответить, если знаете. Представим себе psd макет... Как правильно подойти к созданию MVC на сайте(любого сайта). Как понять сколько контролеров создавать? Нужно для начало создать структуру ссылок??? Вообще с чего нужно начинать создание сайта? Или всё начинается с проектирование базы данных? Спасибо!
P.S. Не знал в какой раздел писать, поэтому написал сюда... И если можно... ссылку на статьи с созданием архитектуры сайта(с учётом макета psd)

Comment: Я полез в гугл, чтобы найти, что такое MVC вообще, и сразу попалась ссылка на хабре (вторая): https://habrahabr.ru/post/181772/ Может помочь

Answer (score 2):

Это вопрос не совсем в формате SO, так как ответ не может быть однозначным, только рекомендации:

> Вообще с чего нужно начинать создание сайта?

Я так понимаю если решили взять MVC за основу - то взять фреймворк с MVC, и установить его start-application. Например на Zend 3 :https://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app . Заработало? Ура, начало сайту положено! А дальше ещё накатим немного общих полезных модулей для вашего фреймворка (например [Zend модули](https://zfmodules.com/)). Всё работает? Крутяк, 80% уже сделано.

> Или всё начинается с проектирование базы данных?

Структура БД создаётся постепенно для стартапов. Не бывает так, что раз и сделали окончательную версию БД. НО как раз перед любым кодом, связанным с данными - сначала идёт структура БД.

> Как понять сколько контролеров создавать?

Контроллер - это мысленное отделение одной логики от другой. Их количество зависит - от того насколько разнообразная логика у вас на портале.

К примеру - решили вы в вашем MVC написать модуль объявлений.  Обычно на начало делают два контроллера - IndexController , который группирует действия отображения разных списков объявлений в разных местах, и OfferController - содержащий действия для работы с одним объявлением (например профиль, редактирование, удаление), но может быть и один контроллер - если молуль планируется совсем кратким(довесочным). А может быть у вас был модуль, и вы хотите добавитиь ещё функционал работы с фотографиями в нём - тогда заведёте ещё PhotoController (при условии что Photo отсутствует как модуль). А может контроллеров быть и по 15 в модуле - если так желает религия лид-разработчика, или если модуль крупный.

Постепенность: обычно было так по моему опыту, делалась базовая "голая" версия проекта, чтобы продемонстрировать заказчику что деньги израсходованы верно. А затем проект обрастал разными модулями, контроллерами, и прочим - усложнение идёт постепенно. Не стремитесь делать сразу окончательную версию своих задумок, итерации - сила.

Comment: К примеру... у меня уже есть свёрстанный сайт в классическом стиле(это где несколько сверстанных страниц в куче,в разных папках и sql) Далее делаем каркас MVC или используем сразу framework. А потом движок... А что мультоязычностью делать(хотя уже в конце...)Вот какая путаница в голове. Ведь существует порядок любого сайтостроения, будь то Новостной портал или интернет магазин...

Comment: @Алексей87К - то что у вас свёрстанный сайт, это "вёрстка" - то есть набор страничек. Если никакого динамического функционала не будет - можно ограничиться и  страницами, если смириться с дубликатами кода. Брать ли фреймворк - зависит от цели, без фрейма имеет смысл писать только если цель - самообучение. Мультиязычность делается средствами любого фрейма. Если ваш сайт - сайт визитка, то там не нужны фреймворки, ибо серверного кода - несколько строчек. Порядок у всех свой - но как правило все начинают с того, что берут что-то знакомое(и уже написанное) за основу.

Comment: А вот что такое Yii framework? Часто слышу о неё. Как о облегчает жизнь? И, если я собираюсь натягивать вёрстку на Wordpress, её стоит применят, или это не сопоставимые вещи и у WP есть свой framework, заменяющий Yii? Я новичок и пытаюсь разобраться! Спасибо

Comment: @Алексей87К Wordpress - это CMS. С CMS можно тоже делать сайты - но там больше работы менеджерской, нежели программерской. А Yii  - это фреймворк (скелет) , конечно фрейм не будет работать с CMS только если CMS сама не написана на фрейме. Разница CMS и фрейма - CMS нужно просто установить, установить плагины - и всё работает, программирования не нужно. Минус - ограниченные возможности, часто - тормозит, масштабируется - часто плохо. Фреймворк - всё пишется самостоятельно. Минусы - многое писать самому, долгое изучение - для возможности делать качественно.

Comment: @Алексей87К зачастую CMS берут за основу проекта, и пишут для неё плагин, по специфике проекта. Например в России так промышляют с битриксом, господи прости

Comment: Спасибо всем за комментарии!!! P.S. Советуют брать за основу Yii framework, а здесь Zend... Так куда идти?